# Why is GRUB failing to install?

Tags: 12.10, server, grub2, raid5

I'm trying to install ubuntu Server to a RAID5 array.  I have three, 3Tb disks, each with a GPT partition table.  I have set up my partitions as follows:

```
/dev/sda
1. 512 Mb physical RAID volume
2. 3 Tb pysical RAID volume

/dev/sdb
1. 512 Mb physical RAID volume
2. 3 Tb physical RAID volume

/dev/sdc
1. 512 Mb physical RAID volume
2. 3 Tb physical RAID volume
```

The raid volumes are grouped into two `md` devices:

```
1. 1.5 Gb RAID5 (mount point:  swap)
2. 6.0 Tb RAID5 (mount point:  /)
```

Installation proceeds normally until it is time to install GRUB2.  I get an error that reads:

```
Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda
Executing `grub-install /dev/sda` failed.
This is a fatal error.
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I would suggest try with another bootloader but i don't know if Ubuntu will let you choice

Comment: @Felipe.M - and what bootloaders would that be? It is more whether the bootloader will run Ubuntu, not whether Ubuntu will let it... You could use [EasyBCD to modify a Dual-Booted Windows bootloader](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/use-the-windows-bootloader-to-dual-boot-windows-vista-and-ubuntu.html). blz - how are you implemeting this? Is this from a working system, or a Live Disk? And shouldn't the installer do this for you? If it boots, it works :-s

Comment: @wilf, this is precisely my problem -- the installer *should* do this, but it fails with the error message I reported above.  Again, for clarity, this is all taking place in the ubuntu-server text isntaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that GPT-partitioned drives require a `bios_boot` partition when used in conjunction with BIOS.  [Here](http://stackful-dev.com/raid-install-ubuntu-server-on-a-large-hard-drive.html) is a tutorial that worked for me.

Also note that one of the drives subtending the RAID array **must** have a `/boot` partition configured.  Again, for clarity, you will need:

1. A small (~1 MB) `bios_boot` partition
2. A `/boot` partition

*begin rant*

Holy uninformative error message, GRUB!  Good lord!

*end rant*

Comment: I don't know what this 'BRUB' is that you tried to install, but *grub* does give a bit more informative error message.

Comment: @psusi, I beg to differ.  The grub error above is what I was presented with, verbatim (minus the typo).

Comment: Yeah, really need <rant> tags...

Comment: Did you not read the first part of my comment?  You weren't installing *grub*.. or was that just a typo?  There are a few goofy forks of grub out there that people use, I think another one was called BURG... at any rate, there should have been another line you cut off above that one saying something about gpt, and no bios_grub found...

Comment: @psusi, I did, hence the bit about the typo =)  I was installing GRUB, but my stupid brain decided to type `BRUB`.